# Making Reusable Function in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use this code frequently and it makes my website slowly load.

```
    $('#start').click(function()  {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop : $('.scroll').offset().top
        },1500);//end animate
    });//end click
```

I used to change the `#start` and `.scroll` everytime. Any tips?

Comment: "and it's make my website slowly load." What makes you think the culprit is this short code snippet? It absolutely has no effect on having a slowly loaded webpage.

Comment: Why would you need to have this code in more than one place? And why would it slow down loading time?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a function.

```
function foo(startElem, scrollElem) {
    $(startElem).click(function()  {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop : $(scrollElem).offset().top
        },1500);//end animate
    });
}
```

Then call it when you need it.

```
foo('#start', '.scroll');
```

Read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it is with passing some parameters

Refer this example

```js
function scrollCommon(startElem, scrollElem) {
    $(startElem).click(function()  {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop : $(scrollElem).offset().top
        },1500);//end animate
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" onClick="scrollCommon($(this), '.one')" data-element="one">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onClick="scrollCommon($(this), '.two')" data-element="one">Two</a></li>
    </ul>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <div class="one">
    <b>One</b><br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    <b>Two</b>
    <br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>Lorem<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the question wether this really has an Impact to your loading time, here another way to set this thing up, using event delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-scroll-target]', function(e){
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( this.dataset.scrollTarget ).offset().top
    });
});
```

`#start` has now become obsolete, every node with a `data-scroll-target`-attribute will have this functionality

```
<div data-scroll-target=".scroll">#start</div>
...
<div class="scroll"> target </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dsx8o04u/